# Optimize Novacode? - Progressive slowdown on large text files creating DOCX

Tags: large-files, novacode-docx

NOTE: From 2000 lines every 1 second to 2000 lines every 15 minutes on large txt file processing.

When using novacode docx on large files I notice building a docx using paragraph adding gets progressively slower as time goes on.

Opening file a 2.2MB for processing with NovaCode...

*** We can see the first 2000 lines are processed in 1 second.

12/30/2015 5:49:51 AM -- Process starts

12/30/2015 5:50:04 AM 2001 of 46085

*** The next 2000 lines take 40 seconds

12/30/2015 5:50:44 AM 4002 of 46085

...Line processing then continues to slow further from 40 to 80 to 160 secs...

...Until over 2 hours later Novacode is still working on this 2MB text file 
...where at the final stages its taking 15 minutes to process 2000 lines.

12/30/2015 8:11:29 AM 44022 of 46085

12/30/2015 8:24:24 AM 46023 of 46085

Finally it does create a perfect DOCX 2 hours later.

- Still the questions are

__What is causing Novacode to slowdown 
  from 2000 lines every second -- to 2000 lines every 15 minutes
  when anding simple text paragraphs line by line?

__Is there any known strategy to optimize or use NovaCode when working on 
large text files.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I would definitely create an issue on the github repo for this  https://github.com/WordDocX/DocX/issues